# how to implement sequences in python?

Tags: python, math

[image: Equation]

I am super confused on how to implement a loop that uses subscripts usually i would simply use a variable instead of subscripts however in this case the variable would be changing due to nth term. For example if `n = 1` and `a0 = 10` then it would be `an = an-1+10 --->(a1 = a0 +10) ---> a1 = (20)`
Than the value of `a1` would be used to find the value of `a2` however our high school teacher only taught us up to loops so , how would we implement `an` and `bn` using only a for loop (use image for reference)

```
a0 = int(input("a0:"))
N =int(input("N:"))
n=0
An = 0
for i in range(0,N): # I want the loop to run N times 
   n = n+1 # I want the value of n to increment by 1 
   An = a0+10 # not sure if this is right could I do An = n-1 *a0 +10
print(An)# to test if it worked
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a simpler example. With the equation u(n+1) = u(n) * 2, you need to multiply by two the previous term. You only need one variable for this, let's call it u. You can then during each loop, add one to u, and give to u this new value, i.e. :

```
u=1
n=0
for i in range(0,100):
    n=n+1
    u=u*2
print(u)
```

You can do this for every sequence. You would have `a=a+10`, and `b=10*n`!

Comment: That is good way of approcahing it ill try it out

Comment: but what is a refering to in your equation , a0 or an

Comment: @pleasebekind It starts as a0, then a1, then a2, then a3, etc... So it's a(i), with i being the current term.

Comment: This code will explain it to you. Try to run it before trying to understand it all, especially the print statement, it's probably too complicated.
`a0 = int(input("a0:"))
N =int(input("N:"))
n=0
an = a0
for i in range(N):
    an=an*2
    print("We are at the",i,". loop. The value of a("+str(i)+") is",an,".")`